# psql 8.4.1 select all the person born in a specific month

Tags: postgresql, date, select, postgresql-8.4

I am supposed to select all the persons born in July (or 07). This did not work:

```
select * from people where date_trunc('month',dob)='07';
```

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "07"
>   LINE 1: ...ct * from people where date_trunc('month',dob)='07';

What is the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from people where to_char(dob, 'MM') = '09';
```

gives you all people who where born in September, if the date of birth is stored in a timestamp table column called 'dob'.
The second param is the date format pattern. All typical patterns should be supported.
E.g.:

```
select * from people where to_char(dob, 'MON') = 'SEP';
```

would do the same.

look [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) for timestamp format patterns in Postgres:

Comment: good link.I were able to find people born on a specific year and month too (YYYY-MM).Thks

Comment: @mamesaye: Link was to the manual of the outdated version 8.2. Changed it to point to version 8.4.

Answer (score 4):

[`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) is meant to format dates. For a condition like yours, [`extract()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) is simpler & faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM   people
WHERE  extract(month FROM dob) = 7;
```

If you want to search for

> a specific year and month too (YYYY-MM)

... like mentioned in the comment, use `date_trunc()` like you had initially. Just compare it to a `date` or `timestamp`, not to a string, which wouldn't make any sense (and was the cause of the error message). To find people born July 1970:

```
SELECT *
FROM   people
WHERE  date_trunc('month', dob) = '1970-07-01 0:0'::timestamp;
```

If performance is relevant, rewrite that to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   people
WHERE  dob >= '1970-07-01 0:0'::timestamp
AND    dob <  '1970-08-01 0:0'::timestamp;  -- note the < with the upper limit
```

Because this form can use a plain index on `people.dob`:

```
CREATE INDEX people_dob_idx ON people (dob);
```

... and will therefore nuke the performance of the previous queries with big tables. Doesn't matter much with small tables.

You could also speed up the first query with a [functional index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html), if needed.